# WCF binding settings - Tell me why?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have hosted a WCF service on my server, From another Server I am calling it using proxy(dll) and using code.

Why do I need to provide settings in code when these settings are already on the server's web.confg ? Tell me Why ?

Example:

Config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding openTimeout="00:10:00" 
                 closeTimeout="00:10:00" 
                 sendTimeout="00:10:00" 
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
        </binding>
```

Then in Code again,

```
        WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
        binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
        binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
        binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
          EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(url + "/_vti_bin/cats/fruits.svc");

        ChannelFactory<SomeSolution.IFruit> factory = new ChannelFactory<SomeSolution.IFruit>(binding);
        factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = creds;
        factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = creds.UserName;
        factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = creds.Password;

        SomeSolution.IFruit proxy = factory.CreateChannel(endpoint);
```

Comment: What happens if you take them out of the code?

Comment: @glenatron settings doesn't work then

Comment: You're mixing two approaches: You either configure everything in the configuration and simply create the service host or client, or you configure everything in code and create channels and stuff yourself. Then the config not being used.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Yes, but if I just keep web.config changes and don't add anything to code, it times out within 1 minute, if I do it in code, it works only

Comment: Could you show us the code that you use where it times out in a minute?

Comment: @CustomizedName As I said: The way you create stuff in your code makes it *not* use the config.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I think I got you now, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you hosted the WCF service in server A, and calling it from another server B which is the client to the service. You hand-crafted the client proxy and did not write codes of reading the app config of the client.

Why would you hand-craft the proxy class? while you could use the generated codes through referencing the service, or running svcutil.exe. The generated proxy classes could read the config by default if you provide an endpoint name defined in the app config. In other words, when the instance of a generated proxy class get created, it will use the config, and you can overwrite the loaded settings in codes dynamically before using the instance if needed.

For common application development, you rarely have a need to hand-craft WCF codes as such, e.g., factory.CreateChannel. I used such low level WCF codes only once for working around a WCF defect.

For common practice of consuming WCF service, there are ton of tutorials in the Internet, for example, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/627240/WCF-for-the-Real-World-Not-Hello-World

Comment: TL;DR version "The server does not send the server timeout values to the client, it must be configured separately"